# fa-IR UTF8 is tick on npi-config,but linux does not show persian character and Qt , too

Tags: linux, qt, fonts, qml, embedded

My Linux ([linux 4.4 friendlyarm with ubuntu core](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/FriendlyCore_(based_on_ubuntu-core_with_Qt))) can show utf8 character but cannot show Persian character. How can I solve this? (I have a Persian file name (.png file) but it shows like:

```
Croot@NanoPC-T2:~# ls
FP  rmn.sh  test.pcm  ▒▒▒▒.png

)
```

the strange character is Persian: `سلام.png`

```
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
fa_IR
fa_IR.utf8
POSIX
```

in `npi-config` in locale, the `fa_IR.utf8` is ticked, but in my Qt, QML project also the Persian character does not show. also, the Farsi font (farsifree) is installed.
Also I set this code for my qt qml project in main.cpp to show persian character but it was not good.:

```
QTextCodec *utfCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"); //creating new utf-8 codec
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(utfCodec);  // setting the utf-8 codec for the tr() tags
```

---

Edit : I also add ttf farsi font to my qrc,and show it:

```
FontLoader { id: fixedFont; source: "qrc:/Far_Abasan.ttf" }//://Far_Abasan.ttf

    Text {
        text: "خامل"
        width: 200
        font.family: fixedFont.name
    }
```

but again not working.

Comment: Maybe QML and/or console uses some another font then _farsifree_? Try to force its loading using [FontLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html) . Also try to list available fonts using `Qt.fontFamilies()` to see if the font is available at all.

Comment: really thanks for your answer, but I loaded `FontLoader { id: fixedFont; source: "//usr//share//fonts//truetype//freefarsi//FreeFarsi-Mono.ttf" }` and add it to my Farsi text, but not show it correctly.

Comment: Is there any help?

Comment: Looks strange. Try to put the font in resource and so load it using [QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont). In the `Text` set the font using [font.family](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#font.family-prop). Check twice you use the right font family name. You can get available fonts list using [Qt.fontFamilies()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#fontFamilies-method). I still think that QML uses some default font that has no persian typeface.